# How to restrict tiff file size using ImageMagick and python?

Tags: imagemagick

I am converting a pdf to .tiff file using ImageMagick and calling it from python using subprocess,run() but, I want the output file size to be limited to a maximum value say 40MB. `-define extent max_value` is not working for tiff like it works for jpeg images.

This is my code:

```
subprocess.run('magick convert -density 150 example.pdf -trim -thumbnail 500 result%04d.tif')
```

Comment: This sounds like an ImageMagick issue and has little or nothing to do with Python.

Comment: Without -trim and without -thumbnail, you can control the file size using -density when reading the PDF file, but you may have to iterate to get the size you want. The define you mention is only for JPG files.  You can generate a file for a small density and get its file size. Then compute the needed density to get the file size you want. Keep in mind that doubling the density will increase the file size by 4x if no compression is used for the TIFF. Also note for IM 7, use magick, not magick convert and not convert.

Comment: Mark, I knew that, but usually reserve doing that only for code. But thanks.